# How can I make hl-line mode not override the color of rainbow-mode?

Tags: font-lock, text-properties, overlays, hl-line-mode

Is there an non-intrusive way to do this?

[image: demo]

I've made a fork of rainbow-mode that uses overlay instead of text properties, which solves this :)

https://github.com/amosbird/rainbow-mode

Comment: Looking at both packages, hl-line mode uses overlays, and rainbow-mode uses font locking. Overlays always take priority over text properties, so I don't think there is simple solution to this.

Comment: I use a custom version of highlight-parentheses (which uses overlays) and it is possible to set its priority overlays to a value higher than hl-line mode.  If that interests you, give it a try.  If you get stuck, consider opening a new question asking how to do that.

Comment: OK. So the only solution to this seems to be an overlay version of rainbow mode.